large language models or generative AI API with memory functionality
I interact with software like GPT via APIs. Is there a way to make it understand me better based on past conversations, so that in future interactions, it can provide more tailored responses based on that understanding?
In GPT, I know this feature is called "Memory", but as far as I understand, the API doesn’t provide memory functionality. How can I achieve this feature? Or does anyone know of other large language models or generative AI tools with memory functionality in their APIs?

You can create memory functionality by passing the previous interactions with the LLM along with the new message to an API call.
For example, with OpenAI API in Python, if you ask a question that requires a previous context, the LLM cannot answer it. In the following example, if you make API calls as follows where the second question depends on what was said in the previous interaction (i.e. it requires the LLM to have a memory), then the LLM will fail to answer correctly.
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-4o-mini",
  messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"}
  ]
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)
# The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020.

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-4o-mini",
  messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
  ]
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)
# Could you please provide more context or specify what event or game you're referring to? That way, I can give you a more accurate answer.

However, if you prepend the previous messages a.k.a. chat history to the current message list, then that will serve as memory and the LLM will answer the question appropriately.
chat_history = [
    {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
    {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
]
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4o-mini",
    messages=[
        *chat_history,    # prepend the previous interactions
        {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
    ]
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)
# The 2020 World Series was played at Globe Life Field in Arlington, Texas. This marked the first time the World Series was held at a neutral site due to the COVID-19 pandemic.

Of course, this will require you to store the previous interactions somewhere especially if you intend to interact with the API across multiple days across multiple sessions. If it's going to be an entirely private conversation, then you have probably store it on your own local machine as a JSON array. On the other hand, if you're building some API, then you probably need to look into cloud options such as MongoDB etc.

What if I need to pass hundreds or thousands of past conversations along with each chat, what is the feasible way to achieve it? MongoDB?

@iMath then you should probably look into summarizing the previous interactions and prepend that summary as context. Otherwise, the above is a solution. Note that the chat_history list can be arbitrarily long.

I found the project suits my needs https://github.com/mem0ai/mem0

@iMath yes, that works but if you want this kind of abstractions, I'd prefer langchain.
